# segment fault for a simple std::shared_ptr construction case

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) I learn that there is a constructor for `std::shared_ptr`:

```
template< class Y > explicit shared_ptr( Y* ptr );
```

And I tried a piece of code as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
  /// block 1
  {
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> s1(new std::string("good"));
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> s2(s1.get()); /// s2
    std::cerr << s2.use_count() << std::endl;
  }
  /// block 2
  {
    std::shared_ptr<int> i1(new int(1));
    std::shared_ptr<int> i2(i1.get());  ///  i2
    std::cerr << i2.use_count() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It causes segment fault for *block 1* but not for *block 2*, but both `use_count` are 1. The difference I can think about is that that `int` is a primitive type while `std::string` is managed by allocator.

I read `bits/shared_ptr.h` of `gcc-4.9` and find that there is a post condition for this constructor:

```
use_count() == 1 && get() == __p
```

### Question 1:

Should `std::shared_ptr` NOT constructed with a raw pointer that has been referenced by *another smart pointer*? In this sense, is the preferred way to use this constructor as follow?

```
std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(...));
```

### Question 2:

Does the standard has explicit requirement for this constructor, or this post condition is ONLY for `libstdc++`?

Comment: The constructor has no way of knowing whether the raw pointer came from `std::shared_ptr`, so it owns all of them. This leads to a double delete in both cases because two smart pointers have ownership of the same pointer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both of these cases are invalid uses of `std::shared_ptr`.

You cannot pass the same raw pointer to **two** `std::shared_ptr` constructors and expect well-defined results.  **Both** `std::shared_ptr`s will believe that they **own** that pointer, and will attempt to delete it when they go out of scope.

This is a double free, and is invalid.

If you want to have two `std::shared_ptr`s that manage the same object, you can construct one of them with a raw pointer (or, better yet, use [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)), and then copy construct/assign the second one from the first one.  This way the memory will only be deallocated (and the destructor for the object fired) when the **last** of those `std::shared_ptr`s goes out of scope.

The reason you're getting a segmentation fault in the first case, and not the second one, is likely because `int` is a trivial type, and therefore you're not looking through a freed pointer to run the destructor of `int`, because it doesn't have one.

Answer (score 3):

This is undefined behavior, we can see this by going to cppreference section for [std::shared_ptr constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) says this (*emphasis mine*):

> **Constructing a shared_ptr using the raw pointer overload for an object
>   that is already managed by a shared_ptr leads to undefined behavior**,
>   even if the object is of a type derived from
>   std::enable_shared_from_this (in other words, raw pointer overloads
>   assume ownership of the pointed-to object).

Both `shared_ptr` will attempt to delete the object they believe they now hold sole ownership for. We know this is undefined behavior by going to the draft C++ standard section `3.7.4.2` *Deallocation functions* which says:

> If the argument given to a deallocation function in the standard
>   library is a pointer that is not the null pointer value (4.10), the
>   deallocation function shall deallocate the storage referenced by the
>   pointer, rendering invalid all pointers referring to any part of the
>   deallocated storage. Indirection through an invalid pointer value and
>   **passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have
>   undefined behavior.** [...]

Ownership can only be shared by using copy construction or copy assignment. The same cppreference page provides a correct example using the copy constructor:

```
 std::cout << "constructor with object\n";
 std::shared_ptr<Foo> sh2(new Foo);
 std::shared_ptr<Foo> sh3(sh2);     // <- using copy construction
```

An alternative method to creating a `shared_ptr` is to use [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), which is safer:

> Moreover, code such as f(std::shared_ptr(new int(42)), g()) can
>   cause a memory leak if g throws an exception because g() may be called
>   after new int(42) and before the constructor of shared_ptr. This
>   doesn't occur in f(std::make_shared(42), g()), since two function
>   calls are never interleaved.

Comment: Sorry I haven't read that note and sorry for asking this question.

Comment: @HongxuChen there is no need to apologize, you did not understand the semantics and you asked a question. You now have your answer.